# SagePay Protocol 3.00 PHP Server Integration Query String POST

Tags: php, server, integration, query-string, opayo

I am a beginner PHP developer and trying to integrate sagepay with my site that would allow customers to access a link on my website 'www.example.com/payment' and fill out a form with the amount they owe me and a corresponding invoice number which I have assigned to them and their account number, their billing details, address, full name, postcode and delivery address which should then create a query string sent to the SagePay server.

Below, I have got an example of the form I will be putting in the site:

```
<form action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" method="post" id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
<input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="Vendorname" />
<input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT" />
<input type="hidden" name="Currency" value="GBP"><br />
<input type="hidden" name="NotificationURL" value="http://example.com/payment/"
<input type="number" name="VendorTxCode" placeholder="Invoice Number" value="123456"><br />
<input type="number" name="Amount" placeholder="Amount" value="250"><br />
<input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description of Invoice" value="Payment for your services"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingFirstnames" placeholder="Firstname(s)" value="Fname Mname"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingSurname" placeholder="Surname" value="Surname"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingAddress1" placeholder="Address Line 1" value="BillAddress Line 1"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingAddress2" placeholder="Surname" value="BillAddress Line 2"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingCity" placeholder="City" value="BillCity"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingPostCode" placeholder="Post/Zip Code" value="W1A 1BL"><br />
<input type="text" name="BillingCountry" placeholder="Country" value="United Kingdom"><br /><br />

<input type="text" name="DeliveryFirstnames" placeholder="Firstname(s)" value="Fname Mname"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliverySurname" placeholder="Surname" value="Surname"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliveryAddress1" placeholder="Address Line 1" value="BillAddress Line 1"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliveryAddress2" placeholder="Surname" value="BillAddress Line 2"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliveryCity" placeholder="City" value="BillCity"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliveryPostCode" placeholder="Post/Zip Code" value="W1A 1BL"><br />
<input type="text" name="DeliveryCountry" placeholder="Country" value="United Kingdom"><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I keep getting the INVALID status error with the error code: 5030 which says: 5030 : We could not process your message, please check your integration settings or contact the support team

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting out with http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/9981/download-document/VspPHPKit.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rik, I've downloaded the file and gone through the templates but because I will not be making use of a basket, just a simple form, I can't make use of the use the code from their integration kit. I think I just need to understand how to collect information from the form, process it and send it to sagepay.

Answer (score 0):

Direct api:
https://github.com/colinbm/sagepay-php

Very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that api is for the direct integration whereas I am looking for the server integration. Thanks